# How to install and import module before call DSC in the same script?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am trying to create a script which will prepare my web server. VM is Windows Server 2016 clean installation without any adjustments and imported modules and configurations. Inside the script, I have a mix of functions and DSC configuration for installing .NET, create directories, join to the domain.
At the beginning of the script, I call:

`Install-PackageProvider -Name Nuget...
   Install-Module xWebAdmin...
   Import-Module ...`

Then some functions, and DSC configurations. 
When I run a script, first go to DSC configuration and displaying error from the image below.

I do not know how and where in my script, first to install all necessary packages and modules and then execute rest of the script and configuration.

As I do not have installed and imported modules xWindowsUpdate, xWebAdministration, this won't execute, even if I put import-module at the beginning of the script.

```
Install-Module -Name xWebAdministration -Force
Install-Module -Name xWindowsUpdate -Force 

Configuration IIS
{  
Import-DscResource –ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration, xWindowsUpdate, 
xWebAdministration

Node "localhost"
{  
    {
        Ensure = "Present" 
        Type = "Directory" 
        DestinationPath = "C:\DSCDeployment"    
    }
```

Any hint and advice?

[image]

Comment: Are your modules being imported prior to defining the DSC configuration?

Comment: I put import at the beginning of the script, but execution stars form DSC configuration which is somewhere in the middle of the script. I tried to put somewhere before call DSC configuration, but I couldn't manage it as I do not know where to put.

Comment: Could you edit your post with the full error text?  I suspect something else is going on here.

Comment: I am not sure what I'm missing and why it first step is skipped. Also, I add Import-Module before DSC configuration but error message is the same.

Comment: Can you run `Get-Module xWebAdministration`?  You shouldn't need to install it every time you run the script.

Comment: I added at the beginning of the script, but it looks like it skip install-module and first go inside DSC configuration (where can't detect required module) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible to do install module and call DSC config in the same file. First, PowerShell will parse the Configuration and will try to resolve the Import-DSCResource keywords (and fail because they're not available). 
It has to be done in 2 separate files...

Answer (score 0):

i did it with an invoke-statement before the configuration

```
$Nodes = @(
    @{ NodeName = 'testserver03'}
   ,@{ NodeName = 'testserver01'}
)

foreach ($Node in $Nodes)
{
    invoke-command -ComputerName $Node.NodeName -ScriptBlock `
            {
                Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force
                Install-Module -Name NetworkingDsc -Force
            }
}

Configuration Monitor
{    
    Import-DscResource –ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'NetworkingDsc'
.....
```